# Submit form using MVC 4 don't trigger my Action specified at my BeginForm

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem to submit my form to a specific method in my Controller.

When the user click on my submit button, the `Index` action is triggered, ignoring my `ValidateLogin` action that was specified at my `BeginForm`

What's the problem with my Form ?

**HTML**

```
@model Login.Models.Autenticacao
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/endless.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>    
</head>
    <body>
            <div id="formAutenticacao">
                <div class="pace pace-inactive">
                    <div data-progress="99" data-progress-text="100%" style="width: 100%;" class="pace-progress">
                        <div class="pace-progress-inner"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pace-activity"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="login-wrapper">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <h2 class="fadeInUp animation-delay8" style="font-weight: bold">
                            <img src="~/Images/Horizonta_com_S.png" />
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="login-widget animation-delay1">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                    @using (Html.BeginForm("ValidateLogin", "Login", FormMethod.Post))
                                    {
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>User</label>
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new {placeholder = "Type user name", Class = "form-control input-sm bounceIn animation-delay2"})
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Password</label>
                                            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new {placeholder = "Type the password", Class = "form-control input-sm bounceIn animation-delay4"})
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="seperator"></div>
                                        <hr>

                                        <input type="submit" value="Go!" />
                                    }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <iframe id="iframePrincipal" height="0" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**Login Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {            
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ValidateLogin(Autenticacao form)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

**Route**

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

**Model**

```
public class Autenticacao
{
    [Required]
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual string Password { get; set; }
}
```

**Firebug**

FYI: I translated the name of my `Action` to a better understand in this question.

[image]

Comment: What does Firebug say? Where is the request going?

Comment: Did you check what route rendered on form tag in generated html (using View Source of browser)?

Comment: @WeSt In firebug says `Reload the page to get source for: http://localhost:53059/Login/ValidateLogin` and all parameters was passed. But my method ValidateLogin just should return a View.

Comment: @SivaGopal <form method="post" action="/Login/ValidateLogin">

Comment: Found my error. In Web.config I comment the following line `<authorization><deny users="?" /></authorization>`

Comment: @Lucas_Santos: Please add your last comment as an answer and accept it when you can. Otherwise, this question stays as "Unanswered".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my error.

In Web.config I comment the following line

`<authorization>
   <deny users="?" />
</authorization>`